# Programmatically track and save changes on a Microsoft Word document

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

I'm looking for a way to create version control for word documents.

Simply users will allow or deny incoming changes but all actions will be on a web application so I need to modify documents programmatically. I've found an api for word document but I don't know where to start.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview?view=common-js-preview

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to develop a Word add-in which can be run on the web. See [Build your first Word task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) for getting started quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The new [Office JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/) is preview and does not yet support capturing the review changes. I think it is only possible by [the C# API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.revisions?view=word-pia)